# How to calculate the time difference between two 24 hour times in SAS?

Tags: date, datetime, time, sas

I have four variables: DATE1, DATE1SLEEPTIME,DATE2, DATE2WAKETIME. The time variables have the TIME. format. I'm trying to calculate the time difference (DURATION) between two 24 hour times, but I'm not getting the correct answer.

For reference:

```
DATE1=10/22/2019 
DATE2=10/23/2019
DATE1SLEEPTIME=20:50:00
DATE2WAKETIME=5:00:00
```

I've tried this:

`duration=INTCK('minute',DATE1SLEEPTIME,DATE2WAKETIME)`

this code resulted in duration=0:15

I also tried

`duration=mod(24+(DATE1SLEEPTIME-DATE2WAKETIME)/3600,24)`

this code resulted in duration=0:00:16.

None of these are correct. The correct answer should be around 530(minutes).

Answer (score 2):

Convert your dates and times into datetimes, then use `intck` with the `dtminute` argument. This will count the number of minutes between two datetimes.

```
data want;
    date1 = '22OCT2019'd;
    date2 = '23OCT2019'd; 
    date1sleeptime = '20:50:00't;
    date2waketime  = '5:00:00't;

    date1datetime = dhms(date1, hour(date1sleeptime), minute(date1sleeptime), 0);
    date2datetime = dhms(date2, hour(date2waketime), minute(date2waketime), 0);

    duration = intck('dtminute', date1datetime, date2datetime);
run;
```

```
duration
490
```

Comment: Or just subtract the two datetime values and divide by 60 since there are 60 seconds in one minute.

Comment: Or use `date1datetime = dhms(date1,0,0,date1sleeptime);` to make it more compact.